# Python - how to use the constant e^

Tags: python, math

How would I implement this in python?

`1 / (1 + e^-(-6.78+(0.04*age)))`

I'm not sure about the `e` part of the formula. Here's image:

[image: img]

Comment: One cannot understand what you want to implement bro... Do you want to implement the number e ? as e=2.71... ? or do you want to use e like, just calculate what ever is up there

Comment: This is a screenshot of the bit of the formula I was given. I think its the math.e function which has been said. [link](http://i68.tinypic.com/w7h0k5.png)

Comment: And do you want to develop a method that will calculate e ? Or you just want to calculate this expression ? and its e to the power of `-(-6.78+(0.04*age))` not e minus something. use ^ for expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you're using is known as the *sigmoid* function. You can build a function that will calculate every sigmoid of x.

In order to use e^(x) you can use the numpy function exp as shown in the example.

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    age = 15
    result = sigmoid(-6.78+(0.04*age))
    print(result)
```

Comment: Note that the sigmoid function is already implemented in `scipy:`: [`scipy.stats.logistic.cdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.logistic.html) and [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use `math.e`:

```
import math
1 / (1+ math.e-(-6.78+(0.04*age)))
```

Comment: I think he means e to the power of -(...). but the question is unclear

Comment: This answer is wrong for two reasons. (1) You forgot to take the exponent, so you're actually returning a subtraction instead of an exponential. (2) There is a `math.exp` function; no need to re-implement it manually using a power of `math.e`.